# "Strip Debug Symbols During Copy" and "Strip Linked Product"

Tags: xcode, xcode4

I read a lot of thing and discovery this configs have 2 side effect:

- Make the binary size smaller
- The program show a better debug crash

I am building program for iOS, so I want my binary to be the smallest possible. This mean:

- If I set **YES** to both config, my binary will be the smaller
- If I set **NO**, I will get better debug crash

So I have to set YES for AppStore version and NO for Debug?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8828232/xcode-should-i-strip-debug-symbols-during-copy

Answer (score 4):

A dSYM file is nothing a "debug symbols file". It is generated when the "Strip Debug Symbols" setting is enabled in the build settings of your project.

The default debug info format for the Debug configuration for new iOS projects is "DWARF with dSYM file", but for new OS X projects is just "DWARF".

If you're running under the debugger, of course, it will just stop at the point of the crash, so you don't need to symbolicate a crash report.So set 'DWARF' when application is in development and set 'DWARF with dSYM' at the time of release.

You should apply this settings as well:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, set it to YES for AppStore build and NO for debugging builds. Even when you build you AppStore version, there is dsym file containing all symbols you need to symbolicate your crash logs.