# What are debug symbols in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

what is a debug symbol? and what is the usage?

Will be able to submit an app with debug symbols to appstore?

Please help!

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: For a really good explanation of what Debug Symbols and DSYM files are see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22460058/how-is-a-dsym-file-created

Answer (score 8, accepted):

dSym are generated when you archived your project.

You don't have to do anything for that.

It allows you to symbolicate your crash log, else it's just meaningless memory adress.

It's kind of a link between the builded code and the source code.

Answer (score 7):

Debug Symbols are additional information about your source code that are used to help debugging. See also this [wikipedia article about debug symbols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debug_symbol). They will not be submitted to the appstore as they are only part of debug-build while you only submit a release-build to the appstore. Though there are some symbols that will be committed for crash logs, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9399728/strip-debug-symbols-during-copy-and-strip-linked-product).