# XCode 7 Crash Reports. How do i read this? UIKit: forwardTouchMethod

Tags: xcode, crash, report

I've been searching for information on crash reports through xcode 7.. Most of the information I have found though has to do with older versions of xcode I think.. I don't know where to begin.. When i go into the organizer window I see this..

[image]

Then when i click on the "Open in Project" button.. I see this

[image]

It doesn't really give me any information except what i see over there.. Opening Thread 0 Thread 1 Thread 2 doesnt show much either. Clicking on each of these things doesn't show me where the problem is in the code..

So where do I go from here? Anything helpful i can read to understand what to do with this crash report?

Answer (score 0):

You need to look in the individual threads for where the error occurred. Here is an example of a crash report with the error circled in red.

[image]

Clicking the error will bring you to where it occurs in your project's code.

Comment: Hi Thank you for the response.. No matter where i click in all the threads it doesn't bring me to where it occurs in code.. Nothing changes on the right side.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you first read about [debug symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28941656/what-are-debug-symbols-in-xcode). An understanding of debug symbols and how memory maps to lines of code is necessary for you to locate the crash in your code. And even then, sometimes this can get really tricky. Good luck!