# What exactly means "Strip native debugging symbols"?

Tags: xamarin.ios, linker

In Visual Studio with Xamarin.iOS there is this option on iOS Build properties page: "Strip native debugging symbols"

(It seems I'm forced to not use this option because then some native static linked libraries (.a) are removed...)

What exactly is included in a generated ipa file if the option is NOT checked ? The C# assemblies (the source code) ? Can anyone really debug the app published to App Store if the option was not active during build ?

Comment: How did you set the Linker Behavior? About "Strip native debugging symbols", please refer to this:https://stackoverflow.com/a/8880533/5474400

Comment: "Link all" (without it does not compile).